# opencl dimensions doesn't work for me

Tags: opencl, dimensions

I learn openCL and I try to testdimension, but they doesn't work for me. Here is the kernel code:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable

typedef struct _data {
    unsigned long wId;  // group_id
    unsigned long iId[4];   // global_item_id
} DATA;

__kernel void tKernel(__global DATA *x, __global DATA *y, __global DATA *z) {
    // x dimension
    int xGrId = get_group_id(0);
    int xLId = get_local_id(0);
    int xGlId = get_global_id(0);
    // y dimension
    int yGrId = get_group_id(1);
    int yLId = get_local_id(1);
    int yGlId = get_global_id(1);
    // z dimension
    int zGrId = get_group_id(2);
    int zLId = get_local_id(2);
    int zGlId = get_global_id(2);

    x += xGrId;
    x->wId = xGrId;
    x->iId[xLId] = xGlId;

    y += yGrId;
    y->wId = yGrId;
    y->iId[yLId] = yGlId;

    z += zGrId;
    z->wId = zGrId;
    z->iId[zLId] = zGlId;
}
```

and here is my host code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define GLOBAL_ITEM_SIZE (16)
#define LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE (4)
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

typedef struct _data {
    unsigned long wId;
    unsigned long iId[LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE];
} DATA;

int main()
{
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_context context = NULL;
    cl_command_queue command_queue = NULL;
    cl_mem xMobj = NULL;
    cl_mem yMobj = NULL;
    cl_mem zMobj = NULL;
    cl_program program = NULL;
    cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret;

    size_t group_size = GLOBAL_ITEM_SIZE / LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE;
    DATA x[group_size];
    DATA y[group_size];
    DATA z[group_size];


    FILE *fp;
    const char fileName[] = "./kernel.cl";
    size_t source_size;
    char *source_str;

    /* Load kernel source file */
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    source_str = (char *)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    /* Get Platform/Device Information */
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

     /* Create OpenCL Context */
    context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    /* Create command queue */
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    /* Create Buffer Objects */
    xMobj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(x), NULL, &ret);
    yMobj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(y), NULL, &ret);
    zMobj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(z), NULL, &ret);

    /* Create kernel program from source file */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {   
        printf("\nFail to build the program\n");
        char buffer[10240];
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Create data parallel OpenCL kernel */
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "tKernel", &ret);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

    /* Set OpenCL kernel arguments */
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&xMobj);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&yMobj);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&zMobj);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

    size_t global_item_size[3] = {GLOBAL_ITEM_SIZE, GLOBAL_ITEM_SIZE, 1};
    size_t local_item_size[3] = {LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE, LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE, 1};

    /* Execute OpenCL kernel as data parallel */
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
                             global_item_size, local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret == CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE) {
        printf("Invalid work group size: error when compute group size: %d/%d", GLOBAL_ITEM_SIZE, LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Transfer result to host */
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, xMobj, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(x), x, 0, NULL, NULL);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, yMobj, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(y), y, 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("%d\n", ret);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, zMobj, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(z), z, 0, NULL, NULL);
    assert(ret == CL_SUCCESS);

    /* Display Results */
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("X dimension:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < group_size; i++) {
        printf("%d: -> group_id %lu ~> work_item_ids: ", i, x[i].wId);
        for (j = 0; j < LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE; j++)
            printf("%2lu, ", x[i].iId[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Y dimension:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < group_size; i++) {
        printf("%d: -> group_id %lu ~> work_item_ids: ", i, y[i].wId);
        for (j = 0; j < LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE; j++)
            printf("%2lu, ", y[i].iId[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Z dimension:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < group_size; i++) {
        printf("%d: -> group_id %lu ~> work_item_ids: ", i, z[i].wId);
        for (j = 0; j < LOCAL_ITEM_SIZE; j++)
            printf("%2lu, ", z[i].iId[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* Finalization */
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(xMobj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);

    free(source_str);

    return 0;
}
```

I build the code on Mac OS X 10.6. and the output was:

```
X dimension:
0: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  1,  2,  3, 
1: -> group_id 1 ~> work_item_ids:  4,  5,  6,  7, 
2: -> group_id 2 ~> work_item_ids:  8,  9, 10, 11, 
3: -> group_id 3 ~> work_item_ids: 12, 13, 14, 15, 

Y dimension:
0: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  0,  0,  0, 
1: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  0,  0,  0, 
2: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  0,  0,  0, 
3: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  0,  0,  0, 

Z dimension:
0: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  0,  0,  0, 
1: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  0,  0,  0, 
2: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  0,  0,  0, 
3: -> group_id 0 ~> work_item_ids:  0,  0,  0,  0,
```

As you can see, the Y is empty (Z dimension must by empty because I didn't set it).
I try to set **y*** parameters in kernel to **x** values and the result was like **x** dimension, so the memory copy is all right. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
                             global_item_size, local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

The third parameter of this call is the number of dimensions of the NDRange space, and you are setting it to 1, one dimension. Set it to 2.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrite the param to number 2. But have another problem yet, with transferring data from device to host:

    **ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, xMobj, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(x), x, 0, NULL, NULL);**

retun number -36 which is **CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE**

Comment: Sorry I did this error, becouse I haven't the same size of array in kernel code structure like host code structure. Now It's all right. Thanks for helping me.